# How to make one relative div cover other relative divs all inside div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot figure out how to make one relative div cover other relative divs all inside div container without using something like `width:-100px;` which instinctively feels to be totally wrong. Are there different means to implement that?

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   <div id="over_div" style="position:relative"></div>
   <div id="down_div" style="position:relative"></div>
   <div id="down_div" style="position:relative"></div>

</div>
```

EDIT:
I should mention that I am adding that covering div via jQuery append ,which adds it somehow not right there but lower, therefore I don't understand why,so I thought  it might be wrong html structure

Comment: Is there a reason why your don't wish to or can't position the inner divs absolutely?

Comment: @JonSG because it is added lower not right over

Comment: @Vinand Now do you, or don't you want this appended div to cover all previous divs or not? What do you want it cover exactly ?

Comment: Widths can't be negative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right. SOmething like this?

```html
<div class="wrapme">
    <div style="top: 35px;left: 200px; background-color: red; height: 50px; width:24px; z-index: 1; position: relative; margin-top: -15px;"> </div>
    <div style="top: 35px;left: 220px; background-color: green; height: 50px; width:24px; z-index: 2; position: relative; margin-top: -15px;"> </div>
     <div style="top: 35px;left: 225px; background-color: blue; height: 50px; width:48px; z-index: 3; position: relative; margin-top: -15px;"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the #over_div a position of absolute. Also another note, it's best practice to use an external css sheet so that you can more easily maintain your styles.

```css
#over_div{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: Rgba(25,25,25,0.5);
  z-index:10;
  height:150px;
  width:50px;
}
#down_div{
  position:relative;
  background-color: red;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
#down_div2{
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;">
   <div id="over_div"></div>
   <div id="down_div"></div>
   <div id="down_div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I adding that covering div via jQuery append , this adds it somehow not right there but lower, therefore is it fine?

Answer (score 0):

In case I understood your request, see the snippet code.

```js
wrap.onclick = function(){
  this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="app">appended</div>');
  app.style.top = -app.offsetTop+"px";
  this.onclick = null;
}
```

```css
div {border: solid 1px gray;height:10%; width:10%;}
#wrap { height:180px; width:320px; }
#app { position: relative; height: 100%; width:100%; background-color: rgba(200,200,200,.7)}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" style="position:relative;">
   <div id="over_div" style="position:relative">1st</div>
   <div id="down_div" style="position:relative">2nd</div>
   <div id="down_div" style="position:relative">3rd</div>
  click anywhere to append the cover div
</div>
```